# How to count string occurrence in My SQL Order by with CASEs

Tags: sql, mysql

We are working on a MySQL search to access articles. There are few rules which are as following.

The search results should be ranked like:

1. All words are in the title (Working)
2. All words are in the article multiple times (Not Working)
3. All words are in the article (Working)
   These 2 might then come into play if none of the above exists…
4. One of the words are in the title (Working)
5. One of the words are in the article (Working)

```
SELECT 
 B.page_id, 
 B.page_name, 
 B.page_description,  
FROM 
 kbs_page_tbl B
WHERE 
 A.page_id = B.page_id 
 AND (
   (
     B.page_name LIKE '%EXAMPLES%' 
     OR B.description LIKE '%EXAMPLES%' 
     OR B.tags LIKE '%EXAMPLES%'
   ) 
   AND (
     B.page_name LIKE '%OF%' 
     OR B.description LIKE '%OF%' 
     OR B.tags LIKE '%OF%'
   )
 ) 
 AND B.company_id IN(4) 
ORDER BY 
 (
   CASE WHEN B.page_name LIKE '%EXAMPLES%' 
   AND B.page_name LIKE '%OF%' 
   AND B.lifetime_views THEN 1 END
 ) DESC, 
 (
   CASE WHEN B.description LIKE '%EXAMPLES%' 
   AND B.description LIKE '%OF%' 
   AND B.lifetime_views THEN 2 END
 ) DESC, 
 (
   CASE WHEN (
     B.page_name LIKE '%EXAMPLES%' 
     AND B.description LIKE '%EXAMPLES%'
   ) 
   AND (
     B.page_name LIKE '%OF%' 
     AND B.description LIKE '%OF%'
   ) 
   AND B.lifetime_views THEN 3 END
 ) DESC, 
 (
   CASE WHEN (
     B.page_name LIKE '%EXAMPLES%' 
     OR B.description LIKE '%EXAMPLES%'
   ) 
   AND (
     B.page_name LIKE '%OF%' 
     OR B.description LIKE '%OF%'
   ) 
   AND B.lifetime_views THEN 4 END
 ) DESC
```

How to fulfil 2nd rule in ORDER BY Clause (All words are in the article multiple times)?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055 - #5 and #3.

Comment: @amandeep Does a search have to read the entire ranking list to sort things based on each matched ranking? Or does it only need to score a single first hit and ignore the rest of the list? The former one using one single complicated query which covers all possible cases will make the performance suffer ,especially from the index's pespective.

Comment: @blabla_bingo, page_name is first priority then description (entire), performance not an issue,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly - you want to check if a string occurs at least twice in anoher string? If yea the maybe you can use REGEXP, eg.
to check whether 'test' occurs twice in a column try something like'

```
select if(aa REGEXP('(test).*\\1'),1,0) from .........
```

Comment: no scenario is , if i searched for "example" , if example keyword comes 2 times in A article and in another  B article comes once, then A article should come first in order by as that article has more then once